# Accidentally deleted laravel.log contents

Tags: laravel

I accidentally deleted the contents of laravel.log
Now, whenever I'm editing a blade, the changes doesn't reflect.
What should I do? Please help.
Thank you

Comment: you should clear your compiled view using `php artisan view:clear`

Comment: oh my god thank you so much!!!

Comment: @RAUSHANKUMAR please help, the controllers don't work anymore too :(

Comment: any errors you are getting?

Comment: it's okay now, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run this artisan command to restore it and clear the view cache:

```
php artisan view:clear
```

and

```
php artisan config:cache
```